# Mysql logrotation doesn't work

Tags: mysql, cron, logs, logrotate

I'm having trouble making Mysql log rotation working. I don't know why this is so complicated , even though I followed documentation and internet advice, still cannot make it work.
I have enabled all 3 logs on Mysql : general log, log error and slow query, under 3 files : `error.log, mysql-slow.log , mysql.log`. All 3 logs function properly. One of these files ( mysql.log ) generates 10 Gbs daily, and I want to logrotate this file every 2 days, meaning I want to always keep the the data from the last 2 days, and keep cycling the data so that it never exceeds 30 Gbs of data, so it would look something like this ( I modified the output, to give you an example of what I want ) :

```
ls -lh
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.1G Apr 18 06:30 mysql.log
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.3G Apr 17 06:28 mysql.log-20210417.backup
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.0G Apr 16 06:28 mysql.log-20210416.backup
```

First I tried modifing the file `/etc/logrotate.conf` , it looked like this :

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# use the syslog group by default, since this is the owning group
# of /var/log/syslog.
su root syslog

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
#compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0660 root utmp
    rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here

/var/log/mysql/mysql.log {

su mysql mysql
       create 600 mysql mysql
       notifempty
       daily
       rotate 2
       missingok
       compress
   copytruncate
    postrotate
        just if mysqld is really running
       if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
          /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping &>/dev/null
       then
          /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs
       fi
    endscript
}
```

I just basically added at the end of the file the part that starts with `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log {`
Then , I created the file `mysql` in `/etc/logrotate.d/` directory and updated the file with the part that starts with `/var/log/mysql/mysql.log {` .

Both of the methods failed (using /etc/logrotation.conf and /etc/logrotate.d/mysql files ), file logs keep piling up more than 2 days :

```
total 52G
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  13K Apr 16 08:41 error.log
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  140 Apr  1 06:25 error.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 5.7G Apr 18 09:37 mysql-slow.log
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 114K Apr 18 19:24 mysql.log
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.1G Apr 18 06:30 mysql.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.3G Apr 14 06:28 mysql.log.1-2021041506.backup
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.0G Apr 15 06:28 mysql.log.1-2021041606.backup
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.2G Apr 16 06:28 mysql.log.1-2021041706.backup
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 9.1G Apr 17 06:28 mysql.log.1-2021041806.backup
```

Furthermore, I noticed that another file is created with "1" at the end of it's name : `mysql.log.1`. Strange.

Another thing that I tried modifying is the `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file:
I tried 2 scripts :

```
#!/bin/sh

# Clean non existent log file entries from status file
cd /var/lib/logrotate
test -e status || touch status
head -1 status > status.clean
sed 's/"//g' status | while read logfile date
do
    [ -e "$logfile" ] && echo "\"$logfile\" $date"
done >> status.clean
mv status.clean status

test -x /usr/sbin/logrotate || exit 0
/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mysql
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/mysql
EXITVALUE=$?
if [ $EXITVALUE != 0 ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t logrotate "ALERT exited abnormally with [$EXITVALUE]"
fi
exit 0
```

It didn't work with neither. Can you please help me with some suggestions/guidelines of what to do next ? Sorry for the long post, thanks.

Comment: Can I confirm the goal here? You would just like to have log files older than 2 days deleted?

Comment: yes, I also posted a ls -lh , with the output of how I want it to look like

Comment: This would be an extra step, but you could have a cron job set up for `root` to delete files older than X days. Here’s a quick example: `0 0 * * * find /var/log/mysql/mysql.log* -mtime +2 -type f -delete`. This will delete files older than 48 hours of age at midnight every day.

Comment: yeah, I understand, but the thing is I want to use the mysql log rotation opton, it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In a situation like this , all related scripts must be checked : /etc/logrotate.conf , /etc/cron.daily/logrotate and /etc/logrotate.d/mysql .

For me the issue was in /etc/logrotate.d/mysql , with the flush-logs commmand, the user wasn't allowed to run that command,